# Inheriting class with multi parameter pack variadic template

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template class with multiple parameter packs, something like this:

```
template <typename... Types>
struct TopicsList { };

template <typename... Topics>
class TheParent;

template <typename... OutputTopics, typename... InputTopics>
class TheParent<TopicsList<OutputTopics...>, TopicsList<InputTopics...>>
{
};
```

I am trying to inherit from this class, like this:

```
template <typename... Topics>
class TheChild;

template <typename... OutputTopics, typename... InputTopics>
class TheChild<TopicsList<OutputTopics...>, TopicsList<InputTopics...>>
    : public TheParent<OutputTopics..., InputTopics...>, public ::testing::Test
{
};
```

But I am getting the following compilation error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class {anonymous}::TheParent<TopicA, TopicB, TopicC>'
 class TheChild<TopicsList<OutputTopics...>, TopicsList<InputTopics...>>
```

Any clues why is it so would be highly appreciated!

Comment: hint: What template parameters does `TheParent` take? What template parameters are you passing into it from `TheChild`?

Comment: Thanks @Barry , that helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
template <typename... OutputTopics, typename... InputTopics>
class TheChild<TopicsList<OutputTopics...>, TopicsList<InputTopics...>>
    : public TheParent<TopicsList<OutputTopics...>, TopicsList<InputTopics...>>, public ::testing::Test
// ....................^^^^^^^^^^^...............^^^^^^^^^^^^^^..............^
{
};
```

?

I mean... if your `TheParent` is declared only receiving a couple of `TopicsList`, you have to maintain the `TopicsList` wrapper passing the parameters from `TheChild` to `TheParent`.